# LibCinder: Default Variable Names for Shader Parameters

Tags: c++, opengl, cinder

I've been working through the 
[OpenGL guide for libCinder](https://www.libcinder.org/docs/guides/opengl/part5.html), in particular the shaders section.

Unfortunately, libCinder doesn't use the OpenGL variable names for default inputs to vertex and fragment shaders. E.g., `gl_position` is remapped to `ciPosition`.

Can anyone provide a list with a mapping from OpenGL to libCinder input variable names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the cleanest way, but you can see them inside the source code [here](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/src/cinder/gl/GlslProg.cpp#L610-L656):

```
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciPosition"] = geom::Attrib::POSITION;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciNormal"] = geom::Attrib::NORMAL;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciTangent"] = geom::Attrib::TANGENT;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciBitangent"] = geom::Attrib::BITANGENT;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciTexCoord0"] = geom::Attrib::TEX_COORD_0;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciTexCoord1"] = geom::Attrib::TEX_COORD_1;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciTexCoord2"] = geom::Attrib::TEX_COORD_2;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciTexCoord3"] = geom::Attrib::TEX_COORD_3;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciColor"] = geom::Attrib::COLOR;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciBoneIndex"] = geom::Attrib::BONE_INDEX;
sDefaultAttribNameToSemanticMap["ciBoneWeight"] = geom::Attrib::BONE_WEIGHT;
```

And also:

```
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelMatrix"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_MATRIX;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelMatrixInverse"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_MATRIX_INVERSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelMatrixInverseTranspose"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_MATRIX_INVERSE_TRANSPOSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciViewMatrix"] = UNIFORM_VIEW_MATRIX;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciViewMatrixInverse"] = UNIFORM_VIEW_MATRIX_INVERSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelView"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_VIEW;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelViewInverse"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_VIEW_INVERSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelViewInverseTranspose"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_VIEW_INVERSE_TRANSPOSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelViewProjection"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_VIEW_PROJECTION;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciModelViewProjectionInverse"] = UNIFORM_MODEL_VIEW_PROJECTION_INVERSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciProjectionMatrix"] = UNIFORM_PROJECTION_MATRIX;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciProjectionMatrixInverse"] = UNIFORM_PROJECTION_MATRIX_INVERSE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciViewProjection"] = UNIFORM_VIEW_PROJECTION;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciNormalMatrix"] = UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciViewportMatrix"] = UNIFORM_VIEWPORT_MATRIX;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciWindowSize"] = UNIFORM_WINDOW_SIZE;
sDefaultUniformNameToSemanticMap["ciElapsedSeconds"] = UNIFORM_ELAPSED_SECONDS;
```